# How to add street and time as text to a photo?

Tags: photos, geolocation

I am looking for a way to automatically add the street address and current time as text to a photo. Failing that, I'm looking for a way to post-process any photo I choose to add that information as text. I would rather not have to write the text myself, but something that uses my current location to automatically add the text.

Is there a way I can do this? Perhaps via an app?

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575)

Comment: There _is_ a problem to be solved here. I think this question is okay (but it would be nice to de-emphasize the "help me find an app" aspect of it).

Comment: I have taken a stab at making the question more about the problem to be solved than an app to be found.

Comment: Are you after something that will update the photo's metadata, or something that will "stamp" the text onto the picture?

Comment: Do not close question. Rephrase seems legit.